# object(stdClass)#5(3 Causes invalid JSON in php

Tags: php, json

I'm having trouble for days when Passing JSON data from PHP to Action Scrip 3.0 .

So, I wanted to at least convert/decode the JSON data in the server side `php` then pass it as a `String` to Action Script.

Anyway my problem here is this: When I do `JSON.decode($myJSONdata)` it only shows `NULL`.
However, using `Var_dump` actually shows all the `JSON data.

So, I went to http://jsonlint.com and it gave me an error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
object(stdClass)#5(3
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Any idea how to fix this?

My JSON data is (UPDATED):

```
{
    "id": 4542471,
    "id_str": "4542471",
    "name": "Sobia Bashir",
    "screen_name": "Sobia",
    "location": "",
    "description": "A woman on the edge!",
    "url": null,
    "entities": {
        "description": {
            "urls": []
        }
    },
    "protected": true,
    "followers_count": 47,
    "friends_count": 61,
    "listed_count": 11,
    "created_at": "Fri Apr 13 21:28:34 +0000 2007",
    "favourites_count": 5,
    "utc_offset": 0,
    "time_zone": "London",
    "geo_enabled": false,
    "verified": false,
    "statuses_count": 729,
    "lang": "en",
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "is_translator": false,
    "profile_background_color": "1A1B1F",
    "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme9/bg.gif",
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme9/bg.gif",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1349587963/Portrait_1_normal.jpg",
    "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1349587963/Portrait_1_normal.jpg",
    "profile_link_color": "2FC2EF",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "181A1E",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "252429",
    "profile_text_color": "666666",
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "default_profile": false,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "following": false,
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "notifications": false
}
```

Comment: This is `var_dump` data.

Comment: As @YogeshSuthar said, please provide the raw json data

Comment: Getting an error related to an error like that implies that you're calling `json_decode` somewhere with the wrong arguments, or there is a blatant syntax error which you're not reading/are ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

> using Var_dump actually shows all the `JSON data

`var_dump()` doesn't produce JSON, only `json_encode()` does.

```
echo json_encode($myObject);
```